# using several rich:orderinglist in the same view with some having buttons hidden (richfaces 4)

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

Hie all, I would like to use two rich:orderinglists in the same view having one with the control buttons and the other without them.

I manage to hide them globaly by introducing :

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
.rf-ord-btn{display:none;}
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

At the beginning of my form.

But then buttons are hidden for all lists...

What would be the right way to limit the re-styling to only one of my lists?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `styleClass` attribute.

```
<rich:orderingList styleClass="list-with-hidden-buttons">
```

and then change the rule to cover only that list

```
.list-with-hidden-buttons .rf-ord-btn {
    display:none;
}
```